# Reset scope interval in angularjs directive creating loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my agnularjs directive I've got object containting logic of some script

```
$scope.slider = {
    increment: 0,
    step: 1,
    positionTop: 0,
    init: function (step, isClick) {
        if(isClick) clearInterval($scope.interval);
        ...rest of script...
```

and then below, after `$scope.slider` is closed (`}`) I have this code

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.slider.changeSlide($scope.slider.step);
    $scope.interval = setInterval(function () {
        $scope.slider.step++;
        if($scope.slider.step === 5) $scope.slider.step = 1;
        $scope.slider.changeSlide($scope.slider.step);
    }, 5000);
});
```

On page load I'm starting `init` method work and then when user additionaly click this html tag

```
<span class="main__last-added-dot"
      data-ng-class="slider.step == 1 ? 'main__last-added-dot--active' : ''"
      data-ng-click="slider.init(1, true);"></span>
```

it clear interval which means that it stop working and I'm not seting new interval because I dont know how. I'm using angularjs $timeout to start interval because div which I'm working on are gathered in backend call so I need to wait for them.

---

I tried to assign interval to another scope variable and call it within like this

in init method within `$scope.slider` object:

```
$timeout(function(){ $scope.startInterval() });
```

below `$scope.slider` object:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.startInterval = function() {
        $scope.interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('fire function interval');
            $scope.slider.step++;
            if($scope.slider.step === 5) $scope.slider.step = 1;
            $scope.slider.changeSlide($scope.slider.step);
        }, 5000);
    };
    $scope.startInterval();
});
```

But it create some kind of loop I don't really know it was working very strange.

What I'm doing wrong how to stop this interval and start it again, after span click i want to clear seconds to 0..

I add [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9WDZkdu1hetunfIvBkMl?p=preview).

Comment: Can you create plunker with this issue scenario?

Comment: Yes but it will be a lot of code because this directive is aroung 100 lines

Comment: Look I tried to keep it as simple as possible https://plnkr.co/edit/9WDZkdu1hetunfIvBkMl?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this below code, also please check this working **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zP61UriGG7H5fhxEttI3?p=preview)** example for your given scenario.

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('myElement', ['$interval', '$timeout',
  function($interval, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.timer=5000;
        scope.step = 1;
        function updateTime() {
          if(scope.step==4) scope.step=0;
          scope.step++;
        }
        scope.stopTime = $interval(updateTime, scope.timer);
        scope.resetTimer=function(step){
          scope.step = step;
          $interval.cancel(scope.stopTime);
          scope.stopTime = $interval(updateTime, scope.timer);
        }
      }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name your function and reset its interval in `init` like this:

```
$scope.slider = {
    increment: 0,
    step: 1,
    positionTop: 0,
    init: function (step, isClick) {
        if(isClick) clearInterval($scope.interval);
        $scope.interval = setInterval(intervalSlide, 5000); // Reset interval here
        ...rest of script...
};

// Name your function, no need to attach it to $scope
function intervalSlide() {
    $scope.slider.step++;
    if($scope.slider.step === 5) $scope.slider.step = 1;
    $scope.slider.changeSlide($scope.slider.step);
}

$timeout(function () {
    $scope.slider.changeSlide($scope.slider.step);
    $scope.interval = setInterval(intervalSlide, 5000);
});
```

Comment: this steps are basically barebone for login of my horizontal slider

Comment: Why do you call `init` in `changeSlide`? You have set an interval, not a timeout, so it can loop by itself.

Comment: When i delete changeSlide in init it will not start working after page load. I'm using $timeout because I'll have async call and need to wait for records to display to gather them to NodeList later on

Comment: $timeout is fine. I meant: use SoC for your functions. `init` should init timer only, `changeSlide` should change slide only. Then it becomes easy to call what you need when you need it.